# Teachable machine on PC

Tags: tensorflow

Hi there i am pretty new to programming, but is it possible to use Google's teachable machine in command prompt on PC? Or it is a special application?
My plan is that.

One folder contains the image 1
Other Folder contains image 2

Then it teaches it self with the images in folder two

Then i have a third folder and only keep the images the third folder which are 50% more likely image 1 or image 2.

Just like on their website but in local pc, and mass scale.

Is it possible or it is too hard just asking :D

https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/image

Comment: OpenCV might help, see https://www.learnopencv.com/tag/image-classification/

Comment: That looks interesting! Thank you.

Comment: I also found something useful, i try to make something with it : https://github.com/tryolabs/luminoth